# React Router Dom V6

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

What is the difference between `Navigate` component and `navigate` from `useNavigate()` hook?.

```
if (therapy !== desiredGroupTherapy || required.includes('admin') && !isAdmin) {
    const pathname = generatePath(pageRoutes.DASHBOARD, {
      groupId: desiredGroupId,
      therapy: therapyForValidGroup,
    })
    navigate(pathname, { replace: true })
    // return <Navigate to={pathname} replace />
  }
```

I have issue with `navigate` here. How that should work: I redirect to that page, but at first time I have no `therapy`, so I should redirect to the same page but my `therapy` now will be equal to `therapyForValidGroup`. I have custom hook `useTherapy()` which takes `therapy` from URL. So at first time when it is undefined it crashes using `navigate` function. But using `Navigate` component, it works fine. So what is the difference?

Comment: please edit you question to be more specific.

Comment: Are you trying to use the `navigate` function ***outside*** a callback or `useEffect` hook? Can you update your post to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we've more context for what the code is doing and what you want to accomplish?

Comment: The difference is that ```useNavigate``` is used in functional components while ```navigate``` is used in class components

Comment: @Icekid The `useNavigate` hook ***returns*** the `navigate` function, so they are both used in React function components. The only way `navigate` can be used in a class component is if it is first accessed via a function component and passed as a prop to a class component.

Comment: @DrewReese, yes, just inside `if`. So I have ProtectedRouteWrapper for each page which checks for a lot of different conditions. In this example, after login I should navigate to Dashboard. Dashboard route looks like that: `${BASEPATH}/:therapy/:groupId/dashboard`
I get groupId from response, but I have no therapy, so in that ProtectedRouteWrapper I get default value for therapy and want to navigate to the same route where I have been, and now I will have therapy in my URL and if that condition will be false ( and it will be ) then I will just render my children.

Comment: @DrewReese it uses a lot of logic...(

Comment: We just need a [mcve], the minimal amount of code to reproduce the issue. We can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see.

Comment: @DrewReese https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-herschel-zdzzlo?file=/src/Dashboard.jsx

Comment: Does this help answer your question about the difference between the `navigate` function and the `Navigate` component? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71784911/8690857

Comment: @DrewReese could you try the example, please? Look inside `Authorization.jsx`. Why app don't work as expected using `navigate`, but it works good if we use `return <Navigate.../>`

Comment: It's because you are calling `navigate` directly in the component body. `Navigate` component works because you can return JSX from the component body to be rendered. Are you preferring to use the `useNavigate` hook and `navigate` function over the `Navigate` component?

Comment: @DrewReese, yes, how i could  use that code with `navigate` from `useNavigate()` hook?

Answer (score 0):

The `navigate` function, when invoked, is a side-effect. The code is calling `navigate` directly in the body of the component as an unintentional side-effect.

Move the logic into a `useEffect` hook.

Example:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { generatePath, useParams } from "react-router";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { usePathPattern } from "./usePathPattern";

export const Authorization = ({ children }) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const userTherapy = params.therapy;
  const name = params.name;
  const pattern = usePathPattern();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userTherapy === "undefined" && name) {
      const pathname = generatePath(pattern, {
        name,
        therapy: "TEST"
      });
      navigate(pathname, { replace: true });
    }
  }, [name, navigate, pattern, userTherapy]);

  return children;
};
```

Comment: so what is the difference in render order between  using `navigate` and `Navigate` component? why we have `no therapy` error with function from hook?

Comment: @DanielSadovskiy `Navigate` is a React component and can be returned from the `Authorization` component body to be rendered.

Comment: I mean why I have no issue using component, but I have using function? What is going wrong exactly under that mechanism?

Comment: @DanielSadovskiy Using the `navigate` function directly in component body is an unintentional side-effect. I'm presuming the issue you are seeing is *some* RRD invariant error saying it can't navigate yet, or the code is render looping. In either case, you need to wait for the component to be mounted *before* you can issue any imperative navigation actions.